# Can the "structural" equivalence between partitions and equivalence relations be expressed as an isomorphism of categories?

Tags: abstract-algebra, elementary-set-theory, category-theory

I have not taken a formal course in category theory, but as part of my abstract algebra class, I was given a brief introduction to subject of categories, so that I better understand and appreciate the recurring themes within abstract algebra (e.g. sub-objects, homomorphisms, isomorphisms, quotient-objects, etc.).

As part of my abstract algebra course, I learned about several instances of "isomorphism of categories", and came to appreciate them as essentially expressing the "structural" equivalence between two types of objects. For instance, I learned that the fact that abelian groups and $Z$-modules (where $Z$ is the ring of integers) have the same "structural" information can be expressed as an isomorphism of categories (i.e. between the category of abelian groups Ab and the category of $Z$-modules $Z$-Mod).

But I have also noticed similar types of "structural" equivalences occurring outside of abstract algebra, even in as simple of a subject as elementary set theory:

From elementary set theory, I know that equivalence relations and partitions are essentially the same, in that the information present within each equivalence relation is just enough to *uniquely* construct the corresponding partition, and vice versa. This seems very similar to the instances of "isomorphism of categories" I encountered within abstract algebra. Thus, I am wondering whether this is indeed another instance of an isomorphism of categories (between a "category" of equivalence relations and a "category" of partitions)?

Answer (score 12):

You can treat a set as a discrete category - the set's elements are the category's objects, and the only morphisms are the identity morphisms. You can then speak of when sets are isomorphic as categories, and the answer is when they are equinumerous as sets. But this view of partitions and relations is completely barren, naked, devoid of structure. It ignores where partitions and relations come from.

The better view is to treat the collection of partitions $P(X)$ and the collection of equivalence relations $E(X)$ on a set $X$ as a *functor* applied to a set $X$ (an endofunctor of $\sf Set$, to be precise). Your statement about the "information present" in a partition is enough to "uniquely construct" an equivalence relation and vice-versa translates to the fact that $P$ And $E$ are *naturally isomorphic* as functors.

The key word is "natural." It is possible for sets to be equinumerous, but not in a "natural" way, or more accurately, not in any way that is free from making arbitrary choices.

In the context of combinatorics, we speak of functors of finite sets as *combinatorial species*. Examples of species (set-valued functors applied to a finite set $X$) are: the power set $\mathcal{P}(X)$, the set of all $k$-subsets of $X$, the set of all graphs with vertex set $X$, the set of all group operations on $X$, etc. Basically, a species is a collection of all examples of some kind of "construction" which uses the elements of $X$. (More precisely, we might say a species is an endofunctor on the skeletal core of $\sf FinSet$.)

So, $P$ and $E$ are naturally isomorphic species. For contrast, consider the species $\mathrm{Lin}(X)$ of all linear orders on $X$ (ways of arranging its elements in some order) and the species of $\mathrm{Perm}(X)$ of all permutations of $X$ (self-bijections of $X$). If $|X|=n$, counting arguments show $|\mathrm{Lin}(X)|=|\mathrm{Perm}(X)|=n!$, so we know $\mathrm{Lin}(X)$ and $\mathrm{Perm}(X)$ are always equinumerous, but $\mathrm{Lin}$ and $\mathrm{Perm}$ are *not isomorphic* functors! (This is because $\mathrm{Lin}(X)$ and $\mathrm{Perm}(X)$ are not equivalent as $S_X$-sets; compare orbits.) There is no "natural" way to turn an linear ordering into a self-bijection or vice-versa, on an arbitrary set, without making some kind of arbitrary choice (like, picking a particular linear ordering and declaring all other orderings are permutations of it - similar to how a vector space has a distinguished origin but an abstract affine space does not).

Comment: Yes, I see now. Does that then also mean for instance that the fact that Z-modules have the same "structural information" as abelian groups (in the sense that the information in an abelian group is enough to uniquely construct a corresponding Z-module and vice versa) has really more to do with natural isomorphisms of functors than with category isomorphisms per se? I'm aware of a similar notion to "category isomorphism" called "category equivalence", which is based on natural isomorphisms. Is what I said above relating abelian groups and Z-modules really more related to "category equivalence"?

Comment: @Logic314 No, ${\sf Mod}_{\Bbb Z}\cong{\sf AbGrp}$ is properly a category isomorphism, not a natural isomorphism. You are not treating $\Bbb Z$-modules or abelian groups like they are "constructed" from some third object, as with $P(X)$ and $E(X)$. (Also, "equivalence" effectively just means "not an isomorphism, but good enough because it gets at least one object of every isomorphism class.") I am also rethinking my answer a bit: even though the functorial view jumps out at me, there is a way to talk about categories of partitions or of sets-with-relations being equivalent. Might update later.

Comment: Re: the end of elemelons' last comment: let $\mathsf{Part}$ be the category whose objects are pairs $(A, P)$ with $A$ a set and $P$ a partition of $A$, with a morphism $(A,P)\rightarrow (B,Q)$ being a function $f:A\rightarrow B$ such that if $a,a'$ are in the same $P$-part of $A$ then $f(a), f(a')$ are in the same $Q$-part of $B$. Let $\mathsf{Equiv}$ be the category whose objects are pairs $(A, E)$ with $A$ a set and $E$ an equivalence relation on $A$, with a morphism from $(A,E)$ to $(B,F)$ being a $g:A\rightarrow B$ such that $aEa'\rightarrow bEb'$. Then $\mathsf{Part}\cong \mathsf{Equiv}$.

Comment: @NoahSchweber This makes so much sense. Yes, indeed, if we consider the category of all equivalence relations on all possible sets, and similarly, the category of all partitions of all possible sets, then the categories are no longer discreate categories, so the category isomorphism is no longer a trivial matter, and actually is meaningful, indeed signifying the "structural" equivalence between the two object types, just as in the case for abelian groups vs. Z-modules, and just as I had expected based on intuition.

Answer (score 2):

Observe that every set is a (discrete) category (the objects are elements of the set and arrows are identities).
Fix a set X. Consider the set of all equivalence relations on X as a discrete category E. Consider the set of all partitions of X as a discrete category P.

Then, there is an isomorphism of categories from E to P.

All set theoretic bijections can be thought of as isomorphisms of categories.